# Creating a Game Board in Python

Tags: python

I am working on a project in which i'm building a text based game. I know what is needed to create the board however I can't get it right. The instructions are below that are to be used and what the output should be.

Create a loop that will run 5 times. Inside the loop, append an empty list to your board. Then start an inner loop that appends a period to this inner list 5 times.
At the end of this function, you should have a board variable that is a list of 5 lists, each sublist containing 5 "."

```
board = []
    per = ["."]
    for i in range(1, 6):
        board.append(i)
        for p in range(1, 6):
            per.append(p)
            return board
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You want your code to do the following:

- make five rows
- in each row, add five periods
- add each row to the board once it is complete

```py
board = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    row = []
    for p in range(1, 6):
        row.append(".")
    board.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt:
To embed an empty list withing a list you could try this:

```
 for i in range(1, 6):
        board.append([])
```

if you print board now it looks like this:

```
[[], [], [], [], []]
```

now to add contents within each empty lists you could do two for loops

1st loop: iterates each empty list in the board

2nd loop: add the number of elements we want within the empty list iterated (in this case 5 dots):

```
for li in board:
    for dot in range(5):
        li.append('.')
```

if board is printed now:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'], ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```